# When writing a custom op, if the output shape is dynamic, how to define the output of infer_shape function?

Tags: mxnet

I'm now writing a custom op, and it's output shape is dynamic, how to define the *output_shape* in *infer_shape* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `infer_shape` function of `CustomOpProp` has an `in_shape` parameter. You can use it to calculate the output_shape dynamically.

If you cannot infer input shape without input data, but can infer maximum shape, then you can use it as commented here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/9758